# Activate and desactivate with same button

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to create a button to activate and deactivate 3 gameobjects, but I don't get it. This is the script I'm using. Can anybody help me?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class OcultarPlayer : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject objeto1;
public GameObject objeto2;
public GameObject objeto3;

void OnMouseDown() {
    if(objeto1.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled == true && objeto2.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled == true && objeto3.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled == true)
    {
        objeto1.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = false;
        objeto2.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = false;
        objeto3.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = false;
    }

    if (objeto1.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = false &&   objeto2.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled == false && objeto3.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled == false)
    {
    objeto1.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = true;
    objeto2.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = true;
    objeto3.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = true;
}

}
}
```

Comment: *but I don't get it* I don't get what you are trying to get here

Comment: @UmairM I'm trying objects disappear when I pulse the button and those objects appear when I pulse the same button again.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @UmairM What's wrong in the code? When I pulse the button the objects disappear but when I pulse it again don't appear.

Comment: Why are you using GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = false; and not simply setActive(false);?

Comment: @Alox The objects are components of my player. I don't want activate/deactivate them, only their renderers.

Comment: Their renderers or their spriteRenderers?

Comment: @Alox Their mesh renderers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something simpler like this:

```
public Renderer objeto1;
public Renderer objeto2;
public Renderer objeto3;

bool enabled = false;
void OnMouseDown() 
{
    objeto1.enabled = enabled;
    objeto2.enabled = enabled;
    objeto3.enabled = enabled;
    enabled = !enabled;
}
```

Comment: Yes! it works. Thanks. I think I've other solution:   else   {    objeto1.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = true;    objeto2.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = true;    objeto3.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = true;  }